# sys.path.append in a module, that is being imported by another module

Tags: python, python-import, directory-structure, sys

When I use sys to import a module, which itself also imports some other modules with sys, there is the following problem with the path: inside module.py In order to import something I have to act as if I am importing from the main.py hierarchy level. This makes the code unreadable, because when someone looks at module.py, they will do not necessarily know that it is imported in main.py and the path will make no sense to them. How do I solve this?

```
    #main.py
    import sys
    sys.path.append('folder')
    import module
    
    #module.py
    import sys
    sys.path.append('path from "module.py" to some package') # does not work
    sys.path.append('path from "main.py" to some package')   # works
```

- main.py
- folder

  - module.py

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what your actual requirement is with proper example? Is it that in module.py you want to use some of the functionalities written in main.py and hence you want to import main.py in module.py?

Comment: I want run main.py | main.py should use a function from module.py | module.py uses a function from another file (which I have not specified in my example). The problem is that the import statement of that other file inside module.py fails if I use  "path from module.py to the required package". Instead it works, if use "path from main.py to the required package" for the sys.path.append() statement in module.py. So it appears to my that the current sys path is always the one of the main.py, even if you call sys from module.py.

Comment: The Problem with that is, that when reading the code of module.py, without knowing where it will be imported to, the "path" inside sys.path.append("path") will appear awkward. Because if you go from module.py p.e. like this "../package", there will be no package. Instead, from the perspective of module.py the package should be at "../../package", but this will not work.